# LWC, set record to database soql from JavaScript with wire and Apex, error

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, lwc

I try to write something to the database soql in JS, but it not works.
When I click to the button 'Add to Cart' then is called handlePlaceOrder().
Here is called Apex method placeOrder('hello') with parameter String.
And then it crashed "an internal server error".
When I executed only Apex method placeOrder('Order01') in Developer Console, it works, writes nameOfOrder to the database.

Here are codes:

html (OK):

```
<template>
  <div class="shopping-cart">
    <template if:true={messageFromMain}>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Items in Cart</h1>
        <lightning-card title="Shopping cart">
          <lightning-button 
            class="slds-m-left_x-small"  
            label="Place order" 
            title="Place order"
            variant="success"
            onclick={handlePlaceOrder}>
          </lightning-button>
        </lightning-card>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template if:false={messageFromMain}>
      <h1>Select the shoes</h1>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS (bug):

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import placeOrder from '@salesforce/apex/ProductMaster.placeOrder';

export default class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {
  nameOfOrder;

  @api messageFromMain;

  @wire(placeOrder, { nameOfOrder: '$nameOfOrder'})


  // handle click to button Place order
  handlePlaceOrder() {
    console.log('It was pressed button \'Add to Cart\'.');

    placeOrder('hello');
  }
}
```

Apex (OK):

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static void placeOrder(String nameOfOrder) {
  Shop_Order__c newOrder = new Shop_Order__c(
    Text__c = nameOfOrder
  );
  insert newOrder;
}
```

Error:

```
Error: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 185265246-97831 (-1502885840)
    at U.B.mk (https://static.lightning.force.com/eu40/auraFW/javascript/Q8onN6EmJyGRC51_NSPc2A/aura_prod.js:656:438)
```

What is not correct on this JavaScript code? [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257058/how-do-i-pass-a-sobject-record-from-lwc-to-a-custom-apex-method-to-persist-data) is an example with similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@wire(placeOrder, { nameOfOrder: '$nameOfOrder'})
```

You might have to delete that line. Your `handlePlaceOrder()` is treated as continuation of that line (ignore newlines), as a handler what to do (callback) when the asynchonous processing finishes. In the answeryou linked compare what you wrote with "fetchedContact"

And in `handlePlaceOrder` I think you need to pass params as JSON object where names match the names of apex parameters. Try

Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Id insertAccount(String n){
    Account a = new Account(Name = n);
    insert a;
    return a.Id;
}
```

Component's relevant html

```
<lightning-button label="test" onclick={handlePlaceOrder}>
</lightning-button>
```

Component's relevant JS

```
import insertAccount from '@salesforce/apex/SomeClass.insertAccount';
export default class SomeComp extends LightningElement {
handlePlaceOrder() {
        console.log('It was pressed button \'Add to Cart\'.');
        insertAccount({ n: 'hello' })
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                debugger;
            });
    }

}
```

Browser's console
[image]

And it saved the name OK

[image]

Comment: I tried. Now, it's without errors, but nothing is written in database. 'hello' [is not](https://pasteboard.co/JVWNR9r.png) in Shop_Order__c. Where is the 'hello' lost?
if I understand correctly, fetchedContact is for get values, I would like set values.

Comment: It's just a string (and not say a helper class object) and you passed the parameter exactly as the name of apex parameter? Works for me, check the extended example.

Comment: It was error in Apex. **It doesn't work with `(cacheable=true)`.**
Correct Apex code:
`@AuraEnabled
public static Id placeOrder(String nameOfOrder) {
    Shop_Order__c newOrder = new Shop_Order__c(Text__c = nameOfOrder);
    insert newOrder;
    return newOrder.Id;
}`
Wrong Apex code:
`@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Id placeOrder(String nameOfOrder) {
    Shop_Order__c newOrder = new Shop_Order__c(Text__c = nameOfOrder);
    insert newOrder;
    return newOrder.Id;
}`
Thanks. @eyescream solved it.

Comment: I don't understand this stackoverflow. Code formatting in comments is not correct. The code in my previous post is so illegible.